# Unable to push images to private docker registry with frontend

Tags: docker

The push refers to repository [127.0.0.1:8080/harshal/my-ubuntu]
Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Answer (score 0):

Finally ... after some time I found solution that issue was with port while pushing always use registry port 5000 and don't use web port 8080 while pushing